# Getting chars from user until he hits coma

Tags: c++

I woule like take input from user(char by char) until he hits `.`(no ENTER).

I have no idea how to do it, because usually input has to be send by ENTER.

Comment: That's a dot or a period, definitely not a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  _cputs( "Type 'Y' when finished typing keys: " );
    char ch;
   do{
      ch = _getch();
      cout<<ch;
   } while( ch != '.' );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that conio.h & co. is not portable - it's available only in few compilers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a platform question (or a terminal question, if your terminal isn't part of your platform), not a C++ question. It's not even guaranteed that every terminal has this capability -- what if the terminal only sends characters when the user hits enter?